# Using Dense_Rank with Convert

Tags: sql-server

I have a LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE field that I'm converting to a date format. The need for that is I have multiple projects with different time stamps on the  same day. My syntax for that is CONVERT(DATE,LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE,101) as TEST_DATE.

What I want to be able to do is apply a DENSE_RANK to this formula at the same time. I can't figure out if that's possible and I've spent a good bit of time trying to find the answer via Googling.

Comment: Have you tried it? Like... `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY something OVER CONVERT(DATE,LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE,101)) as dr`?

Comment: To update on @JNevill's response, you don't even need the "partition by" piece. You can just do `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,LAST_BASELINE_UPDATE_DATE,101)) as dr` (Also, notice that I changed his second "Over" to "Order By")

Comment: I haven't but that formula indicates a syntax error for the second "OVER" and the DATE portion shows incorrect syntax error as well.

Comment: Thanks phroureo. That worked!